# Is there a way to make reference layer in azure maps in powerBI interactive?

Tags: azure, powerbi, geojson, layer, azure-maps

I am looking for solution which would enable me to user multiple layers on map in PowerBI report and would not require uploading any layer data to online service (like ArcGIS map requires to do so). So I guess only option that allows that is Azure Maps & reference layer option.
I managed to add some sample layer in geojson:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
    {"type": "Feature",
    "geometry":
    {"type":"MultiPoint",
    "coordinates": [
[37.64697, 55.72114],
[41.84047723, 58.97371378],
[63.75683563, 60.59060577], 
[44.297396, 33.204791],
[47.75392743, 30.78120229],
[-73.954158, 40.688178],
[-82.78519831, 40.58771651],
[-96.12545437, 42.29971623],
[-99.11535138, 44.17718811],
[-100.3381386, 34.75590794],
[-117.2589776, 36.43625979],
[0.0, 0.0]
]
},
"properties":{
"name" : "Site",
"color":"red",
"marker-symbol":"building",
"marker-size":"large",
"stroke-opacity": 3.0
}
}
]
}
```

Properties: marker-size, stroke-opacity and color works. marker-symbol doesnt work for whatever reason, so i got few questions:

1. Is it possible to make this layer interactive? So the user can use it the same way as main layer? i.e. hoover over to see tooltip?
2. I imagine there is no way to make it filterable since this is not data source and has no relationships...(?)
3. If answer to question 1 is NO, then it is possible to hack it around with displaying some text label next to the shape on map?
4. Is it possible to use some other shape than bubble for point geometry? e.g. custom icon?

Hopefully you could help me out
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Power BI currently lets a single data set connect to a visual at a time. This is the case for all visuals in Power BI. You can sometimes join multiple data sets together if they have a common property.

Azure Maps attempts to work around this limitation by providing the reference layer and custom tile layer functionality in the visual. In regards to your specific questions:

1. There are plans to add interaction/popup support for reference layers in a future update.
2. Data in reference layers is not filterable and there is limited plans around that in the future. Possibly the ability to select a polygon within a reference layer which can then be used as a filter for the main dataset.
3. There is no workaround for this within Power BI.
4. Currently the only other option would be to use the bar chart layer with the bar shape setting set to box. This will provide squares. There are many other visualizations planned for this visual in the future. Note that this visual is still an early preview.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, it is not possible to bring several geometry tables into one visual, but depending on what your data really looks like , you may merge those geojson/tables into one.

Below are answers to your questions. Hope this helps....

> 1. Is it possible to make this layer interactive? So the user can use it the same way as main layer? i.e. hoover over to see tooltip?

Yes it is possible. When you bring things like geojson into Power BI, it is just like other tables.

> 2. I imagine there is no way to make it filterable since this is not data source and has no relationships...(?)

Your example is basically a JSON table with geometry information. With some Power Query M transformation, you can turn that into a table. After that you can build relationship between geojson-turned table with other tables and filter them.

> Is it possible to use some other shape than bubble for point geometry?
> e.g. custom icon?

Handling point object is the simplest because both ArcGIS Map for Power BI and Azure map can take X and Y from imported table. Feature like polygon and polyline will require some workaround involving transforming geometry definition into WKT.
Azure map is relatively new to me, but assuming you choose ArcGIS visual, after you have points displayed in map, you can go to symbology setting in ArcGIS Map for Power BI to choose other symbol. The available option is still limited but at least you can choose more than bubble.

[image: Symbology Setting in ArcGIS Map for Power BI]